# Is there a way to manipulate the code of a running process while its stored in RAM?

Tags: debugging, process

For instance, how you can attach a debugger to a running process. Can one process alter the code in RAM of another process?

Comment: The question is too generic and the answers depends on too many variables such as machine architecture, operating system among other for it to be a good question here.

Comment: This question is very broad. As a result, the best answer is probably the equally broad "yes, but sometimes there are restrictions"...

Comment: To narrow it down, how about on a 32bit machine running Windows?